# .htaccess Redirecting

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make redirects on my server using .htaccess files.

My hierarchy is like this:

File Folder > contains .htaccess and /file/ directory

If someone goes to File Folder, I want it to redirect from just / to /file/ using the .htaccess. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/$ / [L]
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get the error: "The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."